# DH Paramater and Kinematic diagram for 2DOF Cobot

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

Here is my robot model in moveit, I believe the kinematic diagram is not right. Can anyone tell me the correct DH parameter values for this robot model.
As far as I understand the values should be:

```
link       alpha      d(height)       r       theta
  1         90        71.5           58       90+theta1
  2          0          0            165      theta2
```

I have solve the homogenous matrix for them if thetas are 0

```
a1 = [0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
     [1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 58.0]
     [0, 1.0, 0.0, 71.5]
     [0, 0, 0, 1]]
a2 = [0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
     [1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 165.0]
     [0, 0.0, 1.0, 0]
     [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Can someone please point out what mistake I am making here?

[image: Robot kinematic diagram]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* MrDeepak. Could you please *edit your question* to include more information? You say you `believe the kinematic diagram is not right` but also that `the values should be` <table>. What do you mean? Which kinematic diagram is not right? Why do you think it's not right? Where did you get the DH parameters you provided?